# termvector counting keywords in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using elasticsearch 1.5.2.

I want to get the number of time that every keyword is repeated on a stored products in my index.

keywords are : sauces, crèmes, gâteaux.

these are my products:

```
POST test/prod
{
 "titre": "product 1",
 "catégorie": "Epicerie",
 "informations": "Sauces, potages, crèmes & gâteaux. / Composé exclusivement d'amidon de maïs, il vous permet d'alléger vos gâteaux et crêpes ou bien d'épaissir vos sauces, soupes et crèmes. Il rend vos desserts onctueux et légers : il suffit simplement de remplacer la moitié de votre farine par la fécule de maïs. // Poids net : 0,400 kg // Veuillez contacter notre responsable de mise en marché : Distribué par Système U - BP 30159 - 94533 Rungis cedex"
}

POST test/prod
{
 "titre": "product 2",
 "catégorie": "Fruits",
 "informations": "A conserver dans un endoit frais et sec. Idée recette: Madeleines fourrées au chocolat Ingrédients (pour une vingtaine de madeleines) : 100g de farine, 90g fécule de maïs,1 sachet de levure, 3 oeufs,125g de sucre,190g de beurre,1cuillère à soupe d'eau de fleur d'oranger, 1 vingtaine de carrés de chocolat Préparation : Mélangez la farine, la fécule et la levure. Ajoutez le sucre et les oeufs battus. Faites fondre le beurre à feu doux et incorporer le au précédent mélange. Mélangez bien et laissez reposer la pâte une heure au réfrigérateur. Préchauffez le four à 220°C. Beurrez les moules à madeleine, garnissez les moules de moitié, ajoutez au centre un petit carré de chocolat et recouvrez de l'appareil à madeleine. Enfournez pour 5 minutes puis baissez le four à 180°C et poursuivez la cuisson 5 minutes. Sortez les madeleines, laissez-les tiédir et démoulez-les."
}
```

I want to get a result in order desc like this for example:

```
product 1:    
sauces repeated :9
crèmes repeated :8
gâteaux repeated: 2
product 2:    
sauces repeated :8
crèmes repeated :6
gâteaux repeated: 4
```

I used termvector in only one field, however I want to get the result from all document. It was like this:

```
POST test/prod/1/_termvector
{
  "fields" : ["informations"],
  "offsets" : true,
  "payloads" : true,
  "positions" : true,
  "term_statistics" : true,
  "field_statistics" : true
}
```

But I get as a result a very long list which contains all words in this field. I want only as a result my 3 keywords.